# How to read unicode characters from parse.com database in Swift?

Tags: swift, unicode, parse-platform

I am storing the unicode character in the following form in my Parse.com database.

[image: Parse database]

The results I am getting are these
[image: Simulator screenshot]

This is how I am fetching the results

```
  if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
  for object in objects {
  println(object.objectId)
  let pf = object as PFObject
  self.question = pf["Question"] as String
       }}
```

and I am storing `self.question` in a UILabel

How can I show these the unicode characters in simulator as well.

Comment: are you directly printing or storing it in a String variable and printing that String variable?

Comment: Storing it in a String variable, then printing it.

Comment: http://swiftstub.com/486073358/ I tried with normal character and it works. Can you show the code where it if fetching and storing?

Comment: you mean to say self.question.text = pf["Question"] as String?

Answer (score 0):

The only way out is directly store the characters instead of unicode of characters in the Parse database. It supports UTF-8 characters.